# Finding $\frac{a}{b}$ from $a^3 +b^3 - 2a^2b= 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got this equation : $a^3 +b^3 - 2a^2b= 0$ at the last step of a physics question in which I am supposed to find $\dfrac{a}{b}$.  How do I evaluate $a/b$ from this. I tried dividing the whole equation by $a^2b$ and other things, but couldn't reach the desired answer.

Comment: Notice that if $b\neq 0$, then $(\frac{a}{b})^{3}+1-2(\frac{a}{b})^{2}=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide entire equation by $b^3$

Your equation now becomes

$x^3 +1 - 2x^2= 0$ where x = $\frac{a}{b}$

$x^3 - 2x^2 + 1 = 0$

$(x-1)(x^2 - x - 1)= 0$

Now find 3 solutions

Comment: If $b\neq 0$.${}$

Comment: If b = 0 , then a/b does not make any sense in first place. So we would not have to calculate it :P

Answer (score 1):

if $$a^2b\ne 0$$ we get by dividing by $$a^2b$$
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}=2$$ substituting $$\frac{a}{b}=t$$ you will get
$$t+\frac{1}{t^2}=2$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

let $r= \frac{a}{b}$ it satisfies $r^3-2r^2+1=0$. This factorise to $(r-1)(r^2-r-1)=0$, giving $\color{red}{r=1, \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}}$.

Comment: If $b\neq 0$.${}$

Answer (score 0):

One more attempt:

$a^3+b^3 -2a^2b =0;$

$a^3 -a^2b +b^3 -a^2b=0;$

$a^2(a-b) + b(b^2-a^2) = (a-b)(a^2 - (a+b)b)=0.$

1) $a=b;$ I.e

$y_0:=a/b =1;$

2) $a^2 -ab -b^2 =0;$

$y:=a/b$, then

$y^2 -y -1=0.$

$(y-1/2)^2 = 1+1/4=5/4.$

$y_{1,2} = 1/2 ^+_- \sqrt{5/4}.$